# Using WinDbg to analyze .NET dump

Tags: .net, windbg, dump, crash-dumps, sos

I am using windbg to perform an analysis on a dump. Following are the commands that I have ran

1. `.loadby sos mscorwks` - to load the sos dll
2. `~* e !clrstack` - to look at all the threads
3. `~18s` - changed the context to the thread I want to analyze
4. `!clrstack` - to look at the call stack of this thread.

Now, I want to go to each frame in the stack and look at the values of the objects/variables there. How should I proceed?

Is there a way to to find out at what line number in the method the thread is actually stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use !clrstack –l to see local variables.

Also look at this [WinDbg / SOS Cheat Sheet](http://geekswithblogs.net/.netonmymind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx)

This [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) have some great debugging guides